# Does Django cache related ForeignKey and ManyToManyField fields once they're accessed?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Given the following model, does Django cache the related objects after the first time they're accessed?

```
class Post(models.Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

For example:

```
post = Post.objects.get(id=1)

# as i understand this hits the database
authors1 = post.authors.all()
# does this his the database again?
authors2 = post.authors.all()

# as i understand this hits the database
category1 = post.category
# does this hit the database again?
category2 = post.category
```

Note: currently working with Django 1.3, but it's good to know what's available in other versions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first example [the second query is cached](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets). <strike>In the second case (I believe) they will both cause a DB hit unless you use `select_related` on the original query:</strike>

```
post = Post.objects.select_related('category').get(id=1)
```

**EDIT**

I'm wrong about the second example. If you use `select_related` in the original query, you won't hit the database at all again (The ForeignKey is cached immediately). If you don't use `select_related`, you will hit the DB on the first query but the second query will be cached.

From:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#one-to-many-relationships

> Forward access to one-to-many relationships is cached the first time the related object is accessed. Subsequent accesses to the foreign key on the same object instance are cached.
>
> Note that the select_related() QuerySet method recursively prepopulates the cache of all one-to-many relationships ahead of time.

Comment: Still not quite right. ManyToMany queries are not cached at all - they are really just equivalent to reverse FK lookups, so do not get cached except when using the new `prefetch_related` functionality in 1.4.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll handle caching on ManyToMany fields myself when necessary.

Comment: Answer needs to be fixed and better yet tested.  I don't see caching in either case in DJ 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

Django seems to cache `ForeignKey` fields after they are first accessed, but will not cache `ManyToMany`, as mentioned in the comments to the other answer by [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman).  This is also mentioned in the Django docs about [DB optimizations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/optimization/#understand-cached-attributes) (although it doesn't explicitly call out ManyToMany)

> But in general, callable attributes cause DB lookups every time:

I confirmed this with the following test, executed against Django 3.2.8

```
from django.db.models import prefetch_related_objects
from django.test import TestCase
from django.db import connection
from django.test.utils import CaptureQueriesContext

from django.db import models


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class TestQueryCache(TestCase):
    def _create_objects(self):
        author1 = Author(name="first author")
        author1.save()
        author2 = Author(name="second author")
        author2.save()
        category1 = Category(category_name="first category")
        category1.save()
        category2 = Category(category_name="second category")
        category2.save()

        post = Post.objects.create(name="test post", category=category1)
        post.authors.add(author1, author2)
        post.save()

        return post

    def test_foreign_key(self):
        self._create_objects()
        post = Post.objects.get(name="test post")
        with CaptureQueriesContext(connection) as ctx:
            category1 = post.category.category_name
            category2 = post.category.category_name
        print("ForeignKey queries are")
        for query in ctx.captured_queries:
            print(query)
        # this call pattern makes a single query, since foreign keys are cached
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#forward
        # "Forward access to one-to-many relationships is cached the first time the related object is accessed. Subsequent accesses to the foreign key on the same object instance are cached."
        # SELECT "coaching_category"."id", "coaching_category"."category_name" FROM "coaching_category" WHERE "coaching_category"."id" = 1 LIMIT 21


    def test_many_to_many(self):
        self._create_objects()
        post = Post.objects.get(name="test post")
        with CaptureQueriesContext(connection) as ctx:
            authors1 = [author.name for author in post.authors.all()]
            authors2 = [author.name for author in post.authors.all()]
        print("Without prefetching, ManyToMany queries are")
        for query in ctx.captured_queries:
            print(query)
        # This call pattern makes two queries, it seems that unlike ForeignKey, ManyToMany relationships are not cached
        # SELECT "coaching_author"."id", "coaching_author"."name" FROM "coaching_author" INNER JOIN "coaching_post_authors" ON ("coaching_author"."id" = "coaching_post_authors"."author_id") WHERE "coaching_post_authors"."post_id" = 2
        # SELECT "coaching_author"."id", "coaching_author"."name" FROM "coaching_author" INNER JOIN "coaching_post_authors" ON ("coaching_author"."id" = "coaching_post_authors"."author_id") WHERE "coaching_post_authors"."post_id" = 2


    def test_many_to_many_prefetching(self):
        self._create_objects()
        post = Post.objects.get(name="test post")
        with CaptureQueriesContext(connection) as ctx:
            prefetch_related_objects([post], "authors")
            # as i understand this hits the database
            authors1 = [author.name for author in post.authors.all()]
            # does this his the database again?
            authors2 = [author.name for author in post.authors.all()]
        print("With prefetching, ManyToMany queries are")
        for query in ctx.captured_queries:
            print(query)
        # using prefetch allows ManyToMany to be cached, this call pattern makes only a single query
        # SELECT ("coaching_post_authors"."post_id") AS "_prefetch_related_val_post_id", "coaching_author"."id", "coaching_author"."name" FROM "coaching_author" INNER JOIN "coaching_post_authors" ON ("coaching_author"."id" = "coaching_post_authors"."author_id") WHERE "coaching_post_authors"."post_id" IN (3)
```